# build classes from xml file

Tags: c#, xml

First of all, i'm sorry, i know my question will be very basic and stuff but please i would really appreciate some help, i'm under lots of pressure, so making smart comments and being ironic wouldn't help

I have this code:
At least i'm trying.
I have this xml file, i need to save all it's attributes in a class so i can just duplicate it whenever i need to.

I don't know how to.

```
public static void firstFileXml(string sXml1)
{
    var root = XElement.Load(@"sXml1");
    var controlElementsFirst = root.Descendants("books");
}
```

The XML file has attributes like: label, text, label_w etc.
I need a function or somethign that will allow me to enter like:
explore(xmlLocation) and to do the rest.
Because i need to do it for a few xml files

I need to build a class that will allow me to read it.
Suppose i have this file of xml:

WAS

```
    <books>
        <book label='' page='' intro =''/>
        <book label='' page='' intro =''/>
        <book label='' page='' intro =''/>
    </books>
```

IS

```
<SHEET>
<books>
<book label='1' page='1' intro='1'/>
<book label='2' page='2' intro='2'/>
<book label='3' page='3' intro='3'/>
</books>
</SHEET>
```

And so on.
I need first to read this xml file then store the book attributes in a class, so i can use it for hundreds of books later

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // get the xml as a string; note that we could also use
        // Deserialize(Stream) to process a FileStream, but this
        // works fine
        string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\books.xml");
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BookRoot));
        var root = (BookRoot)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        foreach (var book in root.Books)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("label: " + book.Label);
            Console.WriteLine("page: " + book.Page);
            Console.WriteLine("intro: " + book.Intro);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
[XmlRoot("SHEET")]
public class BookRoot
{
    private readonly List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
    [XmlArray("books"), XmlArrayItem("book")]
    public List<Book> Books { get { return books; } }
}
public class Book
{
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("page")]
    public string Page { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("intro")]
    public string Intro { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you are looking for xml serialization

Comment: Not really because they have nodes while i'm using mostly attributes. Please i would really appreciate some sample algorithm or tiny code, just to have an idea

Comment: that is not valid xml...

Comment: i fixed the xml file structure, now it's ok, anyways the xml itself is ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the command line:

```
xsd yourfile.xml
xsd /c yourfile.xsd
```

This will create C# classes using the xml as a template (via schema inference); you can then use those classes with `XmlSerializer`, i.e.

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourRootType));
YourRootType root = (YourRootType)ser.Deserialize(source);
Console.WriteLine(root.Foo);
foreach(Bar bar in root.Bars) {
    Console.WriteLine(bar.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(bar.Id);
}
```

For example, with:

```
<books>
<book label='' page='' intro=''/>
<book label='' page='' intro=''/>
<book label='' page='' intro=''/>
</books>
```

this generates the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="books" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="books" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="book">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="page" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="intro" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and then the C# code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34014
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.18020.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class books {

    private booksBook[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("book", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public booksBook[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class booksBook {

    private string labelField;

    private string pageField;

    private string introField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string label {
        get {
            return this.labelField;
        }
        set {
            this.labelField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string page {
        get {
            return this.pageField;
        }
        set {
            this.pageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string intro {
        get {
            return this.introField;
        }
        set {
            this.introField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

which works fine with `XmlSerializer`, and will correctly deserialize your data, for example:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(books));
var root = (books)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
foreach(var book in root.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("label: " + book.label);
    Console.WriteLine("page: " + book.page);
    Console.WriteLine("intro: " + book.intro);
}
```

Note that you could do it by hand a lot easier:

```
[XmlRoot("books")]
public class BookRoot {
    private readonly List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
    [XmlElement("book")]
    public List<Book> Books { get { return books; } }
}
public class Book {
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string Label {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("page")]
    public string Page {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute("intro")]
    public string Intro {get;set;}
}
```

for example:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BookRoot));
var root = (BookRoot)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
foreach(var book in root.Books)
{
    Console.WriteLine("label: " + book.Label);
    Console.WriteLine("page: " + book.Page);
    Console.WriteLine("intro: " + book.Intro);
}
```

---

With the most recent edit that adds a level into the XML, the attributes need tweaking a bit - to change the root element name, and to add an additional level (`books/book` => `SHEET/books/book`):

```
[XmlRoot("SHEET")]
public class BookRoot
{
    private readonly List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
    [XmlArray("books"), XmlArrayItem("book")]
    public List<Book> Books { get { return books; } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you take a look at my structure of xml? besides, i'm working on visual studio

Comment: @AniAni your xml isn't actually xml, but I'll edit in what it does with something based on that. The xsd.exe tool is a freely available part of the .NET sdk

Comment: Thanks, but it would be better for me if it'S not a tool, well i wish i could understand it but it's difficult for me

Comment: @AniAni you say "I need to build a class that will allow me to read it."; that is **exactly and completely** what the xsd.exe tool **does**. I'm not exactly sure what the issue is here... but you can do it by hand too: see the much shorter (but equivalent) hand-coded version at the end.

Comment: xsd.exe is the way to go, at least for first step (generation of XSD from XML). You could also try https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/ which offers a few more options than xsd.exe for class generation from .xsd file.

Comment: Dear Marc, thank you very much for your code, i really need to do it by hand, i can see it's easier but i don't understand it and i don't have much time actually.

i'm still confused, which is the 'entire' code i should put to execute?

Comment: @Ani I have added examples to both the xsd-generated version and the hand-generated version; both of them work fully with the example xml (and anything similar to that xml with real data).

Comment: Uh, one last question, how do i import the xml file in the hand generated version?

Comment: @Ani the example for loading the data is immediately underneath - at the end of the question. Note that the `Deserialize` method has lots of overloads - I'm using the `TextReader` version, but if you are working with files, there is also an overload that accepts `Stream`

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, please could you write the code for the hand generated version, like you'd insert it in the visual studio? like the whole code

Comment: @AniAni I already have; the code shown **is it**; everything under "Note that you could do it by hand a lot easier:"

Comment: thank you, i just mean, could you just insert a dummy url for my xml file? and something like the whole: namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}

Comment: im so sorry for asking this questions, i realize they are dumb

Comment: @AniAni ...? why? what part of that is unclear? if you can't get it working from the **full code** that *shows it working*, I don't know what to say. What part are you struggling with?

Comment: This might sound dumb, i mean i just don't know, i opened the visual studio, created project with consolea plication, where should i insert the code now?

Comment: @AniAni the classes can go just about anywhere (within reason); the code to do the deserialization should go... where-ever you want to do the deserialization - I can't tell you that. [this should work (link)](http://pastie.org/9520933), but: I strongly recommend becoming more familiar with the basics of getting code running.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, am i reading the file ok? ReadAllText(@"C:\Usersprojects.xml");

Comment: Dear Marc, when i execute this i get just one row.. not all the rows of the xml file...anything i'm missing

Comment: @AniAni cannot comment without representative xml; it should work fine, *if* the xml looks anything like the shape of that shown earlier. If it doesn't share that shape: it will need changes

Comment: it just has a sheet tag like i edited it, does that change anyting?

Comment: @AniAni I can't comment on whether your edit is correct or incorrect without visibility of a: representative xml, and b: your changes

Comment: WELL YES; I EDITED IT; please take a look

Comment: @AniAni sigh; see the new bit at the end of my post

Comment: Ok now it's working again :) but i still get just one line when i write it, but well it's okay, thank you for the help

Comment: could you please take a look at my code, i get just one row

Comment: @AniAni your code is stopping at the `ReadLine`, because **you asked it to**

Comment: ugh, yes, you're right! I'm sorry. So at the end, i have this class, how do i use it somewhere else with different paths of xml?

Comment: @Ani too vague; cannot answer

Comment: well, i mean, this is a class, so i don't have only one xml, i have two xmls and i need the properties for both of them, so how do i get them for the second one without copying the code

Comment: @AniAni you... specify a different path? perhaps by passing in a `string path` parameter to a method?

Comment: yes, i thought of passing a string parameter, but, how do i call it? how do i read all the public string Label and so on? because i need to access them. P.s this is my last questio but you helped me so much

Comment: @Ani usually by, for example, returning that value as a return from the method that takes the path as a parameter; sorry, but this is pretty fundamental stuff.

Comment: eh well, i know it's fundamental, i just needed to be sure, ok then, thank you very much for your help :)